# Parsing "combined" string input in C

Tags: c, parsing, c-strings

Need some tips on what you think it would be the best way to parse a certain input in C.

The input has the format `xx xx xx xx xx xx xx   y1 y2 y3 y4` in which `xx` and `yy` can be any two characters from a to z, but they have different meanings.

The `xx` need to be treated as "individuals" and perform some validations.
The `y0` need to treated as combinations and have a different set validations and operations. (e.g. need to validate y1 and y2 together and then use them to perform an action).

I was using the function `strtoken` to go through the `xx` characters since its delimiter is a space character. However for the second part I need to change that behavior since the code needs to be aware of the 3 consecutive space characters that tells we are now in the second part and it needs to start validating the y combinations.

All tips welcome :) Thanks

Comment: You can find where the break is with `char *ptr = strstr(input, "   ");` If found, write a string terminator `'\0'` at that point, and work with two strings `input` and `ptr+3`.

Comment: I assume there is no constant number of `xx`s or `yn`s? As in, there's a variable number of them? Is there at least an upper bound?

Comment: Hi @Chase there's indeed a constant number of `xx` but not of `y's`

Answer (score 0):

Per the OPs question, there are no limitations on the value contained in `xx`.

I.E. the `xx`  could contain any value from 0x00,0x00 to 0xFF,0xFF

A `switch()` statement could be used, but with no limitations on the values would need 256*256 cases.

Similar considerations apply for the `y0` `y1` `y2` calculations.

Given the above, the code would start with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


// '7' gotten from the OPs example
#define NUM_XX 7   

int main( void )
{
    char xx[2];
    char dummy;
    
    for( size_t x = 0; x < NUM_XX; x++ )
    {
        xx[0] = getchar();
        xx[1] = getchar();
        dummy = getchar();
        
        // calculate index
        int index_xx = xx[0]*256 + xx[1];
        switch( index_xx )  
        // index_xx could be most any value from 0 to 256*256
        {
            case 0:
                ....
                break;
                
            ....
            
            case 256*256:
                ....
                break;
        }
        
        // consume the intervening spaces
        getchar();
        getchar();
        getchar();
        
        char y0[2];
        char y1[2];
        char y2[2];
        
        the `y#`s would be read/processed in a similar loop, exiting the loop on EOF
```